# how to send a collection or array to Notification facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection such as:

```
$users = 
collect([ (object) [ 'name' => 'user1', 'email' => 'user1@gmail.com' ], 
          (object) [ 'name' => 'user2', 'email' => 'user2@gmail.com' ] 
]);
```

Can you help me to understand how to send a collection to a Notification Facade in order to send an email to this users?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a pretty big section in the Laravel docs on how to do this.  Take a look at this, and then perhaps post a bit of what you have tried and what is failing for you specifically.  The directions are pretty easy to get through, but posting what you are having trouble with will allow others to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I  have a mailing list as collection or array, and i want pass it to Notification, but Notification get a notifiable , do exist a way that i pass my array to Notification facade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to send to a collection drawn from a list, and not current users, I think you will need to create the user or person (at least temporarily) if you want to use the Notification facade, as it looks to the database to send from.  From the manual:

> You may send notifications via the Notification facade. This is useful primarily when you need to send a notification to multiple notifiable entities such as a collection of users. To send notifications using the facade, pass all of the notifiable entities and the notification instance to the send method.

To get this working, you will need to `use Notifiable` on the `User` model or whatever model you choose.  Create your new users in the database, and then send this collection to the facade.  If you don't want to keep them in the database after the notification goes out, you can delete them, but I can't tell from your question where the issue lies.  Once you have the collection of `User` objects, you can then call the notification facade on that collection of stored users:

```
Notification::send($users, new WhateverYourNotificationInstanceIsCalled($someNotification));
```

Alternatively, you can create a new 'invite' type thing if you want to set up a structure just for this, but either way you are still creating something in the database.  It keeps your user model clean, but makes just as much work. E.g.

```
 $invite = Invite::create([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'token' => str_random(60),
]);

$invite->notify(new UserInvite());
```

Comment: very thanks, ok,my mailing list is a array and has about 1000 email into it , so, how to i write a Invite include with 1000 mail address?

Comment: If this is a permanent list, create the invites (loop or use the correctly formed array with Invite::insert()) and then follow the answer above and the manual on how to use the notification.

Answer (score 0):

its work for me
i have a foreach loop and 1000 user in my site  ,and every 10 member sleep 2 second then continue
$users = Abonne::select('email')->where('active',1)->get()->pluck('email')->toArray();

```
        foreach ($tab as $i => $user) {
            Notification::route('mail', $user)->notify(new nletter());
               if ($i > 0 && $i % 10 == 0) {
                
                   sleep(2);
               }
```